# WPF change brightness

Tags: wpf, brightness

Well i have a application that is black and white and i need a function to lower the brightness how can i do this? all the white comes from a SolidColorBrush that is saved in a ResourceDictionary(Application.xaml), my current solution is to put a empty window that is back with 80% opacity over it but this does not allow me to use the underlying window..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all your UI elements are using the same `Brush`, why not just modify the `Brush` to reduce the brightness? For example:

```
public void ReduceBrightness()
{
    var brush = Application.Resources("Brush") as SolidColorBrush;
    var color = brush.Color;
    color.R -= 10;
    color.G -= 10;
    color.B -= 10;
    brush.Color = color;
}
```

**Edit after your comment on the `Brush` being frozen:**

If you're using one of the built-in brushes (via the `Brushes` class) then it will be frozen. Instead of using one of them, declare your own `Brush` without freezing it:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush">White</SolidColorBrush>
```

**Edit after Robert's comment on Application-level resources:**

Robert is right. Resources added at the `Application` level are automatically frozen if they are freezable. Even if you explicitly ask for them not to be frozen:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush" PresentationOptions:Freeze="False" Color="#000000"/>
```

There are two ways around this that I can see:

1. As Robert suggested, put the resource at a lower level in the resource tree. For example, in a `Window`'s `Resources` collection. This makes it harder to share though.
2. Put the resource in a wrapper that is not freezable.

As an example of #2 consider the following.

*App.xaml*:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <FrameworkElement x:Key="ForegroundBrushContainer">
        <FrameworkElement.Tag>
            <SolidColorBrush PresentationOptions:Freeze="False" Color="#000000"/>
        </FrameworkElement.Tag>
    </FrameworkElement>
</Application.Resources>
```

*Window1.xaml*:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Foreground="{Binding Tag, Source={StaticResource ForegroundBrushContainer}}">Here is some text in the foreground color.</Label>
    <Button x:Name="_button">Dim</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

*Window1.xaml.cs*:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _button.Click += _button_Click;
    }

    private void _button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var brush = (FindResource("ForegroundBrushContainer") as FrameworkElement).Tag as SolidColorBrush;
        var color = brush.Color;
        color.R -= 10;
        color.G -= 10;
        color.B -= 10;
        brush.Color = color;
    }
}
```

It's not as pretty, but it's the best I can come up with right now.

Comment: the brush is frozen so i cant change it :( is there any way around this?

Comment: This worked like a charm but i have problems when trying to use it in a Style -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443564/wpf-style-problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by changing the Opacity of my root element instead of trying to modify a brush but it would still be nice if some told me if i can do that some how or its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Kent's solution will work if the `SolidColorBrush` is added to the resources at a lower level.  Freezables are automatically frozen when they're added to `Application.Resources`.

Comment: what do you mean by lower level?

Comment: Kent answered this in his second edit - you can add it as a resource of your main Window.